# Run generated use DB command in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have multi databases in SQL Server.

And database design such as "Database1" "Database1_Tmp", "Database2", "Database2_Tmp" e.g.
and in my sql command I want to execute command on current Database and some of commands on selected Database's tmp pair.

I wrote a SQL query as below but it gives me an error

> Incorrect syntax near '@db_Blobname'.

How to write a command to change current Db to running command

thanks

```
..........
---command for DatabaseX
........................
--trying to change current DatabaseX to DatabaseX_Tmp to run command on
    DECLARE @db_Blobname VARCHAR( 255)
    SET @db_Blobname = (SELECT DB_NAME())
    SET @db_Blobname = @db_Blobname+ '_Tmp'
    PRINT @db_Blobname
    USE  @db_Blobname
    GO
............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258848%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) or [`sp_executesql`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to do what you want. But beware: It is not enough to wrap the `USE` inside the dynamic sql. You have to encapsulate the whole statements you want  to do on the other database in this dynamic sql call. 
Citing from the exec page:

> Changes in database context last only until the end of the EXECUTE statement. For example, after the EXEC in this example, the database context is master:
>
> USE master EXEC ('USE pubs') SELECT * FROM authors

So your code looks something like this, assuming you have a table "foo" in your database:

```
DECLARE @db_Blobname VARCHAR( 255)
DECLARE @stmnt VARCHAR(8000)
SET @db_Blobname = (SELECT DB_NAME())
SET @db_Blobname = @db_Blobname+ '_Tmp'
SET @stmnt = 'USE '+@db_Blobname+'; SELECT * FROM foo' 
EXEC (@stmnt)
GO
```

Comment: hallo thnks for your answer ..i have tired the snippet but it gives error as 'Invalid object name 'SampleTable''...

Comment: Here code snippet that i tried........                        DECLARE @db_Blobname VARCHAR( 255) SET @db_Blobname = (SELECT DB_NAME()) SET @db_Blobname = @db_Blobname+ '_Tmp' PRINT @db_Blobname USE master EXEC ('USE '+@db_Blobname )                                                    SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM SampleTable